# Doors: Edit OLE using DXL

Tags: edit, ole, ibm-doors

I have a Doors object in a module which has an embedded (OLE) spreadsheet. I need to update some of the cell values (depending on the values of other objects in the module) using a DXL script. I have done some searching and I cannot find anything that looks like an example. I assume that the DXL script will need to open the object, make it's changes and then close the object.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: This seems to be the same that your http://stackoverflow.com/q/39898881/4434393

Answer (score 0):

This thread is really old but if you still need help with this...Off the top of head, I think the way to go about this is to first make a copy of the OLE outside of DOORS, make your changes, and then put it back into DOORS.

To make a copy of the OLE outside of DOORS you can check out this thread:
https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=454298c1-c144-43e7-bc55-af8a6057b500

To put it back into the object text, you can do it similarly using oleInsert() which you can lookup in the DXL Reference Manual.

Comment: Link only answers are not considered good practice. Please include some code snippets to help the OP. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer